# How to wget a zip file from box?

Tags: wget

I am trying to use `wget` to download this publicly shared zip file from box https://imperialcollegelondon.app.box.com/s/71ki6qw8hjr3olyzmy05lye6le1bqyk5

It comes from this repository https://github.com/HaziqRazali/Using-Eye-Gaze-to-Forecast-Human-Pose-in-Everyday-Pick-and-Place-Actions

I tried using `wget https://imperialcollegelondon.app.box.com/s/71ki6qw8hjr3olyzmy05lye6le1bqyk5` but I get a text file. How do I download it using wget?

Comment: The short answer is you don't (with wget). That's how Box has been "designed".

Comment: You get a text file, because the link you posted actually displays a text file, and to be exact, a HTML file. You need to somehow extract from this HTML code (which is quite obfuscated, as I look at it) the actual link to the file. At least in Firefox, when you try to download the file with a browser, you have the option to copy the actual download link. Try to get that link and download it via wget.

Comment: may be it is because I have a Box account but I when going (in FF) to the imperialcollegelondon.app link, it takes me (as expected) to Box where I can simply click on Download. The download icon in the top bar of Box shows that the file is 4.2 Gb and this method is in common with other downloads from links to files provided in the likes of Dropbox. After downloading the file to my local disk, I would then be in a position to extract the contents from the zip and perform any other required tasks on them.